# Can I apply CSS to swing text components?

Tags: java, css, swing

A number of swing text components will interpret HTML. I'd like to style this HTML with CSS if possible. Any one know how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Jaxx Framework](http://www.aboutus.org/JaXxFramework.org) allows you to do this.

Comment: Hi, thanks for response. I did see Jaxx, but I'm wondering if it can be done in native Swing.

Comment: No it can't. Thats why you need a framework. Or rather it can't without you coding a CSS engine yourself.

Comment: How about doing Swing with Jelly. Yes, its another framework :(