# How to show scrollbar in Swing's JOptionPane.showOptionDialog?

Tags: html, css, swing, scrollbar

In our Swing application, we show error messages using **JOptionPane.showOptionDialog**. However, some of the messages are long and we would like to **limit the height** of the dialog and **show a scrollbar**. We thought of using HTML and CSS in the dialog text to limit the height and show scrollbar, but it seems Swing's HTML & CSS [is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057137/css-with-swing) [quite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937393/can-i-apply-css-to-swing-text-components) [limited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872871/which-html-tags-are-supported-in-swing-components).

Can anyone thing of a way to do it, other then developing our own dialog to show error messages?

Thanks
splintor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `message` parameter to the `showOptionDialog` method is of `Object` type. The [API documentation](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) specifies different behaviours depending on what type is passed there. What should be helpfull in your case is the possibility of passing `Component` object. This way you can pass any component, including `JScrollPane` which will handle scrollbars if necessary. So if your message is in String msg instead of passing it directly you should construct something like this: `new JScrollPane(new JLabel(msg))`.

Answer (score 2):

What you show on the `JOptionPane` is an `Object`. While you usually use a `String`, nothing stops you from displaying a non-editable `JTextArea` (which has scrollbar behavior built in, I believe) or a `JScrollPane` containing a large `JLabel` (or anything like that).

You'll want to set the `PreferredSize` on the JScrollPane, and perhaps also `setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy` and `setVerticalScrollBarPolicy`.