# How use pre-wrap with swing HTML text?

Tags: java, html, swing, text

How can I use the CSS white space property
pre-wrap with a Swing HTML text component?

Answer (score 6):

You can try https://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/ which supports CSS 2.1 or write your own view (ParagraphView extension in the HTMLEditorKit)

Comment: Flying-soucer says: "It cannot be used for user-editable content; output is read-only." so I guess its not an option, since I would like to have it editable.

Comment: To do it by myself by creating a variant of a Kit, do you think reading core Swing by Kim Topley would be a good preparation?

Answer (score 1):

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937393/can-i-apply-css-to-swing-text-components) might help, they recommend using the [Jaxx Framework](http://www.aboutus.org/JaXxFramework.org)

**edit** website recently went down, I'll leave the link there incase it gets brought back

[here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jaxx/?source=navbar) is the sourceforge link

Comment: [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jaxx/?source=navbar) is the sourceforge, any general info was on that website, or on discussions about it on websites like SO